# mplayer does not work when Python script run in background

Tags: python, linux, background-process, mplayer

I have a python script that plays some audio files with mplayer.
This is how I call mplayer in the code:

```
subprocess.call(["mplayer","-msglevel","all=-1",audiofile])
```

it works fine if I run the script in foreground...
However if I run the script in background like

```
sudo python script.py &
```

I cannot get any audio... why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mplayer FAQ](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/faq.html#idp61977408):

> Q: How can I run MPlayer in the background?
>
> A: Use:
>
> ```
>   mplayer options filename < /dev/null &
> ```

In python, use [`stdin` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) to pass null file.

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as nul:
    subprocess.call(['mplayer', '-msglevel', 'all=-1', audiofile], stdin=nul)
```